# Why does changing the evaluationDate multiple times lead to a performance lag?

Tags: programming, quantlib, swaption

I am simulating an swaption strategy through time.  Following the examples in the Python Quantlib cookbook, as I progress through time I am updating the internal evaluation date

```
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate= todays_date
```

The first few iterations its reasonably fast, but after about 10 or so this line of code takes forever. What's going on? How can I keep it fast?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with the current version of SWIG, which we use to generate Python bindings to the underlying C++ library.  See https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues/212 for details and workarounds.